# How to add waits in-between pictures

Tags: python, time, turtle-graphics

I want to make two pictures that go on top of each other after I press the 'w' key to create a walking animation:

```
#Imports
import turtle
import time

#Registers Gifs
turtle.register_shape("ZeldaBackToolless1.gif")
turtle.register_shape("ZeldaBackToolless2.gif")

Zelda = turtle.Turtle()
Zelda.penup()


def move_up():
    if Waiting == True:
        time.sleep(.2)
        Zelda.shape("ZeldaBackToolless1.gif")
        Waiting = False
    else:
        time.sleep(.2)
        Zelda.shape("ZeldaBackToolless2.gif")
        Waiting = True



turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(move_up, "w")
```

If there's a way to make a boolean statement in the `move_up()` function with the boolean statement saving which state it was previously at, that would work great, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I hate to suggest it, the easy way at this level of programming is to use a global state variable:

```
waiting = True

def move_up():
    global waiting

    time.sleep(.2)
    if waiting:
        Zelda.shape("ZeldaBackToolless1.gif")
    else:
        Zelda.shape("ZeldaBackToolless2.gif")

    waiting = !waiting
```

Even shorter, you can use your flag as a list index:

```
waiting = True

def move_up():
    global waiting
    display = ["ZeldaBackToolless1.gif", "ZeldaBackToolless2.gif"]

    waiting = !waiting
    time.sleep(.2)
    Zelda.shape(dislpay[waiting])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I came from C# so I was trying to use stuff like "Public bool waiting" but that didn't work so I started to panic.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that both your solution, and that of @Prune, are ill-considered.  By using `time.sleep()` you're blocking other turtle events.  If this is eventually intended as a *wait* image, then the last thing you want to do is block the thing you're waiting on.  This really should instead be done with timer events:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def walk():
    screen.onkeypress(None, "w")  # disable handler in handler

    def stop_walk():
        zelda.shape("image_2.gif")

        screen.onkeypress(walk, "w")  # restore event handler

    zelda.shape("image_1.gif")

    screen.ontimer(stop_walk, 200)  # in the future, in milliseconds

screen = Screen()

# Registers Gifs
screen.register_shape("image_1.gif")
screen.register_shape("image_2.gif")

zelda = Turtle()
zelda.penup()

screen.onkeypress(walk, "w")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

This will allow other turtle events to continue during the waiting period.

Comment: Literally just having this problem xD Thank you so much